# Dynamically creating classes with specific CodeAttributeDeclarations

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, dynamic-class-creation, dynamic-class

I have a need to have custom code attributes that output something like "DataType(DataType.Text)"

I'm currently attempting to use CodeAttributeDeclarations.

But, something like this adds extra parenthesis:

```
var cad = new CodeAttributeDeclaration("DataType(DataType.Text)");
newProperty.CustomAttributes.Add(cad);
```

So, that code ^^^ outputs this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)()]
```

And, what I need would be this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
```

Comment: Does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131669(v=vs.110).aspx help?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on @mjwills comment, but have you tried this:

```
var cad = new CodeAttributeDeclaration("DataType", new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodePrimitiveExpression(DataType.Text)));
```

Comment: That throws some red squiggly lines under the second "DataType.Text", so I had to wrap it in quotes for the code to build.

But, it doesn't give me what I need -- it outputs this: [DataType("DataType.Text")]

Comment: And, also this code doesn't work for me either:

                        cad2 = new CodeAttributeDeclaration("DataType",
                    new System.CodeDom.CodeAttributeArgument[]
                    {
                             new System.CodeDom.CodeAttributeArgument("DataType", new CodePrimitiveExpression("DataType.Text"))
                    });

Comment: Perhaps you are missing some using statements for this code - it did compile for me, though I'm sure I had to import something, possibly multiple things for it. When I get home I can check on this for you.

Comment: These are the only two usings I had to import to get it all to compile:
`using System.CodeDom;`
`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`